# MongoDB-design for revisioned data

Tags: mongodb, database-design, revision-history

There are many articles and SO questions about MongoDB data-model for storing old revisions of documents.

However, I found nothing satisfying one of my requirements; I need to be able to retroactively query the database to unambiguously find all documents that matched an arbitrary criteria for a given point in time.

To clarify, I need to be able to efficiently answer the question;

> "Which documents (and preferably versions) matched criteria {X:Y...} at time T".

Pseudocode:

```
/* Would match a version that were active from 2010 - 2016-05-01 with zipcode 12345 */
db.my_objs.find({zipcode: "12345", ~time: ISODate("2016-01-01 22:14:31.003")~})
```

I haven't managed to find any solution, neither on google nor myself. I have tried;

1. Having a simple "from"-timestamp on data, and then select "the first item before my queried timepoint, that also matches other criteria", but I have not managed to express that in Mongo.
2. Having a from/to on each version, and whenever I write a new version, update "to" on the previous version to match from on the new version. However, I have not found a way to do this atomically or with eventual consistency, meaning multiple updates could wreak havoc and create ambiguous timelines. (Double entries for the same timepoint)

Any ideas?

**edit**
an **undesirable** example query for #1

```
db.my_objs.find({
    data : {
        $elemMatch : {
            from : {
                $lte : ISODate('2015-01-01')
            }
        }
    }
}, {
    "data.$" : 1
}).forEach(function (obj) {
        if(obj.data[0].state == 'active') {
        printjson(registrar)
    }
})–
```

Comment: could you show your query for 'point 1'?

Comment: As I wrote, I have not been able to express such query?

Comment: ok, got that - was thinking that you had a sketch of that

Comment: Well, for example this, but it means all the filtering must be done client-side, without indexing and potentially wasteful network-usage.

db.my_objs.find({data: { $elemMatch: { from: { $lte: ISODate('2015-01-01') }}}}, { "data.$": 1 }).forEach( function(obj) {
    if ( obj.data[0].state == 'active' ) { printjson( registrar ) }
})

Comment: you can use elemMatch to filter out `active` as well - but be aware that elemMatch returns ***ONLY*** first match

Comment: Yes it would match any version created before the given time that had "active" set to yes. But no guarantees of that being the _active_ version on the given time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115847/discussion-between-profesor79-and-rawler).

Answer (score 0):

aggregation framework and `$unwind` phase which transforms array into single document so we can create sophisticated `$match`  condition

> Example Document

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("577275589ea91b3799341aba"),
    "title" : "Test of design",
    "firstCreated" : ISODate("2016-06-28T13:02:16.156Z"),
    "lastUpdated" : ISODate("2016-06-28T13:02:16.156Z"),
    "firstAuthor" : "profesor79",
    "lastAuthor" : "Rawler",
    "versions" : [{
            "versionId" : 1.0,
            "dateCreated" : ISODate("2015-10-10T00:00:00.000Z"),
            "datePublished" : ISODate("2015-10-12T00:00:00.000Z"),
            "isActive" : false,
            "documnetPayload" : {
                "a" : 1.0,
                "b" : 2.0,
                "c" : 3.0
            }
        }, {
            "versionId" : 2.0,
            "dateCreated" : ISODate("2015-12-10T00:00:00.000Z"),
            "datePublished" : ISODate("2015-12-31T00:00:00.000Z"),
            "isActive" : true,
            "documnetPayload" : {
                "a" : 1.0,
                "b" : 3.0,
                "c" : 30.0
            }
        }, {
            "versionId" : 3.0,
            "dateCreated" : ISODate("2016-01-31T00:00:00.000Z"),
            "datePublished" : ISODate("2016-02-21T00:00:00.000Z"),
            "isActive" : true,
            "documnetPayload" : {
                "a" : 11.0,
                "b" : 3.0,
                "c" : 31.0
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

> Aggregation framework example

```
db.rawler.aggregate([{
            $match : {
                "_id" : ObjectId("577275589ea91b3799341aba")
            }
        }, {
            $unwind : "$versions"
        }, {
            $match : {
                $and : [{
                        "versions.dateCreated" : {
                            $gt : ISODate("2015-10-10T00:00:00.000Z")
                        }
                    }, {
                        "versions.dateCreated" : {
                            $lte : ISODate("2016-01-30T00:00:00.000Z")
                        }
                    }
                ],

                "versions.datePublished" : {
                    $gt : new Date("2015-10-13T00:00:00.000")
                },
                // "versions.versionId" :{$in:[1,3,4,5]},

            }
        }, {
            $sort : {
                "versions.dateCreated" : -1
            }
        },

    ])
```

Comment: "Shift data process to application", can be done using almost any design. (For example in the example I gave you on request)

The wish/desire here was to quickly be able to answer the question "which documents (and preferably versions) on a given time, had the attribute X set to Y", server-side and preferably at least helped by indexes. I don't see how do that using this proposed schema. How would such query look?

Comment: what is standard size of single document?

Comment: Single document-version; 1-2KB. (Up to 25 versions over it's lifetime)

Comment: Your $elemMatch query doesn't answer my question "which documents (and preferably versions) ON a given time, had the attribute X set to Y". It answers "which documents have had X changed to Y _at any point AFTER_ the given time".

Comment: If my answer helped you please accept it see this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer